# How to paginate a trie, so you can find 100 words matching prefix in the trie, starting at a paginated offset?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, pagination, trie

I am using a [trie](https://gist.github.com/tpae/72e1c54471e88b689f85ad2b3940a8f0) made to work on alphabets/scripts from any language.

```
class TrieNode {
  constructor(key) {
    // the "key" value will be the character in sequence
    this.key = key;

    // we keep a reference to parent
    this.parent = null;

    // we have hash of children
    this.children = {};

    // check to see if the node is at the end
    this.end = false;
  }

  getWord() {
    let output = [];
    let node = this;

    while (node !== null) {
      output.unshift(node.key)
      node = node.parent
    }

    return output.join('')
  }
}

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.base = new TrieNode(null)
  }

  insert(word) {
    let node = this.base

    const points = Array.from(word)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]
      if (!node.children[point]) {
        const child = node.children[point] = new TrieNode(point)
        child.parent = node
      }

      node = node.children[point]

      if (i == word.length - 1) {
        node.end = true
      }
    }
  }

  contains(word) {
    let node = this.base

    const points = Array.from(word)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]

      if (node.children[point]) {
        node = node.children[point]
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }

    return node.end;
  }

  find(prefix) {
    let node = this.base
    let output = []

    const points = Array.from(prefix)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]

      // make sure prefix actually has words
      if (node.children[point]) {
        node = node.children[point]
      } else {
        // there's none. just return it.
        return output
      }
    }

    const stack = [node]
    while (stack.length) {
      node = stack.shift()
      // base case, if node is at a word, push to output
      if (node.end) {
        output.unshift(node.getWord())
      }

      // iterate through each children, call recursive findAllWords
      for (var child in node.children) {
        stack.push(node.children[child])
      }
    }

    return output
  }
}
```

Here is how you can find all words matching prefix. [These scrabble words](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zeisler/scrabble/578378ae0f056273b281081fb62f9c7c3aa84f60/db/dictionary.csv) were used (`tmp/scrabble.csv`).

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Trie = require('./Trie')

const words = fs.readFileSync('tmp/scrabble.csv', 'utf-8')
  .trim()
  .split(/\n+/)
  .map(x => x.trim())

const trie = new Trie()

words.forEach(word => trie.insert(word))

console.log(trie.find('zy'))
[
  'zygodactylous', 'zygomorphies', 'zygapophysis',
  'zygapophyses',  'zygomorphic',  'zymologies',
  'zygospores',    'zygosities',   'zygomorphy',
  'zygodactyl',    'zymurgies',    'zymograms',
  'zymogenes',     'zygotenes',    'zygospore',
  'zygomatic',     'zyzzyvas',     'zymosans',
  'zymology',      'zymogram',     'zymogens',
  'zymogene',      'zygotene',     'zygosity',
  'zygomata',      'zyzzyva',      'zymurgy',
  'zymotic',       'zymosis',      'zymoses',
  'zymosan',       'zymogen',      'zymases',
  'zygotic',       'zygotes',      'zygosis',
  'zygoses',       'zygomas',      'zydecos',
  'zymase',        'zygote',       'zygose',
  'zygoma',        'zygoid',       'zydeco',
  'zymes',         'zyme'
]
```

However, search `find('a')` will find over 10,000 matches (words starting with `a`). If this were a web app, you might not want to show all 10,000 at once, maybe only 100 or 1,000 at a time. How could you implement a pagination system against this trie? Is it possible?

From my initial thought-attempts, I was trying to think how you could keep track of the "path" you left off with in the trie (say we are paginating 100 matches/words at a time). So I am trying to modify this function:

```
class Trie {
  // ...

  find(prefix, max = 100) {
    let node = this.base
    let output = []

    const points = Array.from(prefix)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]

      // make sure prefix actually has words
      if (node.children[point]) {
        node = node.children[point]
      } else {
        // return path [-1] since there is no match?
        return [output, [-1]]
      }
    }

    const stack = [node]
    const pathStack = [[0]]
    while (stack.length) {
      const path = pathStack.shift()
      node = stack.shift()
      // base case, if node is at a word, push to output
      if (node.end) {
        output.unshift(node.getWord())
        if (output.length === max) {
          return [output, path]
        }
      }

      // iterate through each children, call recursive findAllWords
      let i = 0
      for (var child in node.children) {
        pathStack.push(path.concat(i++))
        stack.push(node.children[child])
      }
    }

    return [output, [-1]]
  }
}
```

Maybe this is partially correct? But I don't see how to use the path to jump back to the right spot on the next query.

```
[
  [
    'abye', 'abut', 'abri', 'abos', 'ably', 'able', 'abet', 'abed',
    'abbe', 'abba', 'abas', 'aals', 'aahs', 'azo',  'ays',  'aye',
    'axe',  'awn',  'awl',  'awe',  'awa',  'avo',  'ave',  'ava',
    'auk',  'att',  'ate',  'ass',  'asp',  'ask',  'ash',  'art',
    'ars',  'arm',  'ark',  'arf',  'are',  'arc',  'arb',  'apt',
    'ape',  'any',  'ant',  'ani',  'ane',  'and',  'ana',  'amu',
    'amp',  'ami',  'ama',  'alt',  'als',  'alp',  'all',  'ale',
    'alb',  'ala',  'ait',  'ais',  'air',  'ain',  'aim',  'ail',
    'aid',  'aha',  'ago',  'age',  'aga',  'aft',  'aff',  'adz',
    'ads',  'ado',  'add',  'act',  'ace',  'aby',  'abs',  'abo',
    'aba',  'aas',  'aal',  'aah',  'ay',   'ax',   'aw',   'at',
    'as',   'ar',   'an',   'am',   'al',   'ai',   'ah',   'ag',
    'ae',   'ad',   'ab',   'aa'
  ],
  [ 0, 1, 17, 0 ]
]
```

And plus, the words appear to be in unusual order, maybe I am not inserting them the correct order?

This way, in theory, if you had the `path`, then when you call `find(prefix, startAtPath)`, you would pass the `startAtPath` as a second parameter, and start the search from that point forward, to get the next 100 words. I haven't seen any "trie pagination" examples on the web, so maybe it's not a thing that's possible, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TrieNode.constructor` add a `this.count` property.

In `insert`, update the counts for the insertion.

In `find` add `startAt` and `max` parameters.  As long as `node.count < startAt` you will skip past `node` (do not add its children to `pathStack`) and decrease `startAt` by `node.count`.

And then you collect up to `max` words to return.

This allows you to skip past previous results without having to enumerate them. You do not need to pass in the `path`, just where you expect to start.

The cause of your order problem appears to be that you are using `unshift` instead of `push`.

---

Here is your code edited to give the right answer.  I also fixed a minor bug that your output order depends on the order in which `node.children` was inserted. This will work if you load the trie in alphabetical order, but not otherwise.

```
class TrieNode {
  constructor(key) {
    // the "key" value will be the character in sequence
    this.key = key;

    // we keep a reference to parent
    this.parent = null;

    // we have hash of children
    this.children = {};

    // check to see if the node is at the end
    this.end = false;

    // count how many words are at this node or below.
    this.count = 0;

    // Ensure children are in the right order.
    this.lastChildKey = '';
  }

  getWord() {
    let output = [];
    let node = this;

    while (node !== null) {
      output.unshift(node.key)
      node = node.parent
    }

    return output.join('')
  }
}

class Trie {
  constructor() {
    this.base = new TrieNode(null)
  }

  insert(word) {
    let node = this.base

    const points = Array.from(word)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]
      node.count++
      if (!node.children[point]) {
        const child = node.children[point] = new TrieNode(point)
        child.parent = node
      }

      node = node.children[point]

      if (i == word.length - 1) {
        node.end = true
      }

      // If words were inserted out of order, fix order of children.
      if (node.lastChildKey <= point) {
        node.lastChildKey = point
      }
      else {
        // Need to fix order of children.
        let keys = Object.keys(node.children)
        keys.sort()
        let orderedChildren = {}
        for (const key in keys) {
          orderedChildren[key] = node.children[key]
        }
        node.children = orderedChildren
      }
    }
  }

  contains(word) {
    let node = this.base

    const points = Array.from(word)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]

      if (node.children[point]) {
        node = node.children[point]
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }

    return node.end;
  }
  find(prefix, startAt, maxCount) {
    let node = this.base
    let output = []

    const points = Array.from(prefix)

    for (const i in points) {
      const point = points[i]

      // make sure prefix actually has words
      if (node.children[point]) {
        node = node.children[point]
      } else {
        // there's none. just return it.
        return output
      }
    }

    const stack = [node]
    while (stack.length) {
      if (maxCount <= output.length) {
          return output
      }
      node = stack.shift()
      if (node.count < startAt) {
        startAt -= node.count
      }
      else {
        // base case, if node is at a word, push to output
        if (node.end) {
          if (0 < startAt) {
            startAt--;
          }
          else {
            output.push(node.getWord())
          }
        }

        // iterate through each children, call recursive findAllWords
        for (var child in node.children) {
          stack.push(node.children[child])
        }
      }
    }

    return output
  }
}

exports.Trie = Trie
```

Here is your demo program edited for the changes.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const Trie = require('./Trie')

const words = fs.readFileSync('tmp/scrabble.csv', 'utf-8')
  .trim()
  .split(/\n+/)
  .map(x => x.trim())

const trie = new Trie.Trie()

words.forEach(word => trie.insert(word))

console.log(trie.find('a', 0, 12))

console.log(trie.find('a', 6, 6))
```

Comment: This means every time a word is added, you would have to update all the count properties (if you add a word after initial pass at constructing the trie), is there no other way?

Comment: @Lance You only have to update the count properties for the path to that word.

Comment: Ok, what is the count if not the index then? Can you describe in slightly more detail what the count is and what it should be set to?

Comment: @Lance The count is the count of how many words there are at that node and below.

Comment: @Lance I modified your code in accord with my suggestions.  Pagination works on my system.